# WPF: Strecht a Path without changing its form

Tags: wpf, layout, dynamic, path, size

I wanted to create custom shaepd labels to symbolize the progress like in a wizard.
But when I set the Strech-Property to Fill, the angels of the Paths are different.

[example screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU9V6.png)

XAML-Code:

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationStepLabel" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Grid>
                    <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"  Data="M 0,0 h 50 l 5,20 l -5,20 h -50 l 5,-20 l -5,-20" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="2" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,0" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
</Style>

...

<Label Style="{StaticResource NavigationStepLabel}" Content="Start"> 
    <Label.Background>
         ...
    </Label.Background>
</Label>
```

Is there a way to set the size of the path dynamicly to the label without having different angeled arrows?

Comment: Set Stretch to Uniform or UniformToFill.

Comment: @Clemens if I set it to Uniform, all paths are the same size but all are too small for the text. If I set it to UniformToFill the form is being kept, but the paths are getting scaled in height as well and then they are out of the bounds of the container they are in and they have differnt heights.